# Batch find string in file then read x number of next lines

Tags: batch-file

This is one .txt file and I would like to look for a name (lets say "Name 1") and then read the next x number of lines to set variables.

example I look for "Name 1" and in return I first get "Fish", then "potato".

```
Name 1
var1=fish
var2=potato

Name 2
var1=crab
var2=tree

Name 3
var1=bait
var2=water
```

Comment: I edited the title if that's what you meant, was missleading.

Comment: Errrmmm... Oops! My fault ^^' I had it open in one tab and wondered that it was the exact same one. I am an idiot and sorry!

Comment: I cannot find a specific question in your post. Please read the [tour] and learn [ask]! By what criteria do you know when to stop reading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO is not a free "write-my-code-and-do-my-work" community. Next time when you are asking a question please show some effort. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't work. For now, here is your code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET inputfile=input.txt
SET linestoread=2
SET searchstring="Name 1"
SET found=0
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%L IN (%inputfile%) DO (
    IF !found!==1 (
        IF !linestoread!==0 GOTO BREAK
        SET /a linestoread=!linestoread!-1
        FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%A IN ("%%L") DO (
            ECHO %%A
        )
    )
    IF "%%L"==%searchstring% SET found=1
)
:BREAK
```

`SET inputfile=input.txt` is the path to your text file.
`SET linestoread=2` is the number of lines to read after you've found your search string.
`SET searchstring="Name 1"` is the search string.

Comment: Thank you, I apologize for the poorly formatted question. I first tried doing if statements for each string but that was a terrible way of doing it, I also tried using a for loop as you did but I could not figure out how to make it work properly, when I look at your code now I see that I missed a way to end the loop once it was found and read. 
Again, thank you for the answer and I apologize if I made a bad question. It's my first question :)